Try to unset laravel cookies in middleware
I am try to unset cookies in Laravel. I tried multiple answers from existing Stackoverflow answers about this but did not succeed.
middleware code -
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);
    if (!$request->query('ref') ) {
      // Add a cookie to the response that lasts 5 years (in minutes)
       Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('referral'));
      //$response->cookie( 'referral', encrypt( $request->query('ref') ), 525600 );
    }
    else {
        if( $request->query('ref') ) {
            return redirect($request->fullUrl())->withCookie(cookie()->forever('referral', $request->query('ref')));
        }
    }

    return $response;
}


Please check this code
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // Check if 'ref' query parameter exists
    if ($request->has('ref')) {
        // Redirect with the 'referral' cookie set to last forever
        return redirect($request->fullUrl())
            ->withCookie(cookie()->forever('referral', $request->query('ref')));
    }

    // If 'ref' is not present, forget the 'referral' cookie
    Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('referral'));

    return $next($request);
}


if cookie is set with true condition then this condition "Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('referral'));"

what is the true?

solution is ot working
